# Oracle Apex, change the automotive download path to a specific directory path

Tags: oracle-apex

Using Oracle Apex, I was able to create a download link that would download a txt/csv file using PL/SQL Procedure. At the moment, the file is being downloaded automatically into the 'Download Folder' when the link is clicked on. Is there a way to set the automotive download path to a specific directory path e.g. C:\Users\fi\Documents?

Answer (score 2):

No this is not something that can be set from APEX.

Typically browsers remember the most recent location a file was downloaded to and use that as the default location when a new file is attempting to be downloaded.

Even if you could, specifying an absolute path like `C:\Users\fi\Documents` would also not be compatible between operating systems. If a users was on Linux, there would be no C drive.